# How deep can I bury a 1 MHz transmitter

Tags: rf, radio, wave

So in designing a deep underground sensor network, my team wants to use a 1 MHz radio, but we cannot determine a way to model the soil, so as to calculate how deep i can bury a radio for showing proof of concept. The soil we are going to be using will have low humidity.

If there is any advice out there please let me know. thanks

Comment: Get a shovel and start digging?

Comment: here's some interesting information about ground penetrating radar http://www.sensoft.ca/FAQ.aspx#HowDeepGPR

Comment: a *fast* shovel

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for this document: -

[image]

Google also diclosed [this](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1019&context=computerscidiss) document called Channel Characterization for Wireless Underground Sensor Networks.

There is [this one](http://www.ece.gatech.edu/research/labs/bwn/surveys/underground09.pdf) too called Signal propagation techniques for wireless underground communication networks.

Google is your friend